# Basic HTML calendar screw up

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a basic calendar project and i want to have buttons to go through months.

The button works for `console.log` so it must be something wrong with my anonymous function

```
const today = new Date();
const calMonth = today.getMonth();
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", event => {calMonth--});
```

The whole thing on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/CoCedric/pen/KGNWgy

Comment: It's really unclear what you are expecting to have happen with the code you posted here, and it is possible that you might receive some negative feedback as a result. unfortunately, a CodePen isn't really a replacement for posting a [mcve] **in the question body**.   What you have currently posted in the question body suggests you are expecting something to change, maybe in an HTML display, but you aren't actually showing any code that would write anything to HTML, much less update the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that clicks the prev/next buttons are only setting the value of `calMonth`. Also, on that note, `calMonth` is declared as a `const`, meaning you can't change its value.

Here's what you can do:

1. Change the `const` to `let`
2. Wrap the code that sets the innerHTML of getHead and renders the days into a function.

   ```
   function renderCalendar() {
     getHead.innerHTML = monthFran[calMonth];
     for (let i in allDays) {
       let printedDay = i - calDate.getDay();
       allDays[i].innerHTML = (printedDay < 1 || printedDay > monthEnd[calMonth]) ? "" : printedDay;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Call that function when you click the prev/next buttons as well as at the end of the code to render the days.

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((btn) => {
     btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
       if (e.target.classList.contains('bak')) {
         calMonth--;
       } else {
         calMonth++;
       }

       renderCalendar();
     });
   });

   renderCalendar();
   ```

Of course, that solution isn't perfect/optimized in any way, just letting you know what you can do.